# Concatenate strings in nested dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below dict `d`:

```py
{
 1: {1: {'text': 'Contact', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 2: {1: {'text': 'My email', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
     2: {'text': 'is', 'x0': Decimal('279.552')},
     3: {'text': 'domain@example.com', 'x0': Decimal('290.868')}
}
```

That I am trying to transform. Each dict corresponds to a line, and each nested dict, to a word/series of words on that line.

I am trying to transform it so each dict equals equals one line - where the words are concatenated, and the key is changed to `row`

Expected output:

```
 1: {'row': 'Contact'},
 2: {'row': 'My email is domain@example.com'}
```

I am not sure how to go about this? Can anyone guide me in the right correction?

Comment: Why do you name your keys 'row' ?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need.

```
from decimal import Decimal
d = {
 1: {1: {'text': 'Contact', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 2: {1: {'text': 'My email', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
     2: {'text': 'is', 'x0': Decimal('279.552')},
     3: {'text': 'domain@example.com', 'x0': Decimal('290.868')}
    }
}

result = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    result[k] = {"row": " ".join(n["text"] for _, n in v.items())}       
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: {'row': 'Contact'}, 2: {'row': 'My email is domain@example.com'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple list comprehension:

```
d = {1: {1: {'text': 'Contact', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')}}, 2: {1: {'text': 'My email', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')}, 2: {'text': 'is', 'x0': Decimal('279.552')}, 3: {'text': 'domain@example.com', 'x0': Decimal('290.868')}}} 
new_d = {a:{'row':' '.join(i['text'] for i in b.values())} for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{1: {'row': 'Contact'}, 2: {'row': 'My email is domain@example.com'}}
```